# How to get rid of debsums reporting mismatches for core packages?

Tags: ubuntu

I use `debsums` to daily check changes to installed packages on multiple servers. The issue is that some packages start reporting mismatches every so and so and even if I reinstall the package, after few days the mismatches reappear. This is happening across multiple machines and regularly. I would love to understand why is this happening and how to fix it. All that is on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.

Examples of reported changes:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/share/man/man1/sbt.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/libkmod2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/old.libgbm.so.1.0.0
```

I reported this to Ubuntu, but I did not get any response, so I would like to get to the bottom of this but I do not understand why is happening. What is changing those files?

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1681129
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1681126

Comment: Your disk system is corrupting the files.

Comment: On 6 independent servers?

Comment: Well, most of the are shared objects... if you have installed the `prelink` package, that would modify those.  No idea about the man page or changelog files though.

Comment: Like yesterday I went over all servers and reinstalled those packages to get rid of them. And then today another file was found changed: `/usr/share/doc/module-init-tools/changelog.Debian.gz` I do not have `prelink` installed.

Comment: Maybe there is some automatic update happening, which is breaking those.